# I want update value in second textfield when i type something in first Textfield

Tags: wicket

How it will implemented with wicket. 
When a single digit entered in second textfield automatically same changes appear in first textfield :
my code:

```
txtLtpPriceCE.add(new AjaxFormSubmitBehavior("onkeyup") {
        @Override
        protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            System.out.println(txtLtpPriceCE.getInput());
            showCalculatorModel.setTxtIntrinsicValueCE(txtLtpPriceCE.getInput());
            target.addComponent(txtIntrinsicValueCE);
         }

         @Override
         protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
             throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
         }
});
```

My component:

```
final TextField txtLtpPriceCE = new TextField("txtLtpPriceCE",
             new PropertyModel(showCalculatorModel, "txtLtpPriceCE"));
item.add(txtLtpPriceCE);

final TextField txtIntrinsicValueCE = new TextField("txtIntrinsicValueCE",
             new PropertyModel(showCalculatorModel, "txtIntrinsicValueCE"));
item.add(txtIntrinsicValueCE);
txtIntrinsicValueCE.setOutputMarkupId(true);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want the text fields to have the same value all the time you should use one model for both. Then you just have to update the other text field.

```
IModel<String> model = new Model<String>();
TextField<String> textfield1 = new TextField<String>("field1", model);
textfield1.setOutputMarkupId(true);
TextField<String> textfield2 = new TextField<String>("field2", model);
textfield2.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onkeyup") {
  protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
      target.addComponent(textfield1);
  }
});
```

Comment: +1 Maybe it would be better to use [`onInput`](http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/09/effectively-detecting-user-input-in-javascript) instead of `onKeyUp`, though.

Comment: what could we do if the fields are in completely different panels?

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference.  textfield2 updates textfield1 directly regardless of the parent component.

Answer (score 1):

Add a behavior (onUpdate) on your first component. Then update the model of the second component and at the end update the second component (add it to the request target).

```
yourFirstComponent.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
      @Override
      protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
          yourSecondComponentModelValue = yourFirstComponentModelValue;
          target.addComponent(yourSecondComponent);
      }
});
```

Comment: hi...magomi & Till i edited my post & give u a reference code...plz tell me how i set one immidately updated value of one component to other

Comment: Your componente should (must) be backed by a model. All you have to do is to set the object behind the model.

Comment: i edited code of component with model. is that correct or some mistake is there?

Comment: This will not work because you are using a model (at least the name of the object indicates so) as the model object. Looks like you should get back to how use models. I'm afraid this is much more than what can explained in 600 characters in this comment ;-)

Comment: and what if the fields are in different panels?